# Permission denied in push or clone from cPanel remote

Tags: git, ssh, cpanel, git-clone, git-remote

After Add Repository in cPanel and add remote with under command :

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@domain.com:3031/home/user/book
```

And use :

```
git push origin master
```

Enter ssh password
I get error message **Permission denied, please try again.**

Answer (score 0):

These possibilities are there:

1. Remote repository does not have write permissions.
2. You are providing a wrong password or if you are trying ssh with public and private key    combination, they are not matching.
3. Please open git bash and do "ssh -vvv user@domain.com:3031" and try to debug the verbose logs.